# Silverlight file upload - file is in use by another process (Excel, Word)

Tags: silverlight, excel, upload, openfiledialog

all. I have a problem with uploading of the file in Silverlight application. Here is a code sample. In case when this file is opened in other application (excel or word for example) it fails to open it, otherwise it's working fine. I'm using `OpenFileDialog` to choose the file and pass it to this function.

```
    private byte[] GetFileContent(FileInfo file)
    {
        var result = new byte[] {};

        try
        {
            using (var fs = file.OpenRead())
            {
                result = new byte[file.Length];
                fs.Read(result, 0, (int)file.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // File is in use
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Is there any way i can access this file or should i just notify the user that the file is locked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should notify the user that the file is currently in use by another program.  If another program has the file open with a lock that does allow a shared read there is no way to bypass this lock.